# c How to write a program that counts how many words are in a sentence without using strings

Tags: c

So i'm trying to write this program but i cant use strings and have to use the getchar function. this is what i have so far but its not working, but it compiles. When i run it it doesn't come back with the right amount of words. Ive also tried putting words += 1 but that didnt help either.

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main()
{
char ch;
int words = 1 ;

    printf("Enter a sentence ended by a '.', a '?' or a '!': ");
     ch = getchar();
     while (getchar() !='\n');      
{

    if (ch == ' ')  
    words++;

}
    printf("Total number of words:%d\n", words);


   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `while(anything);` is a loop with no body, because of the `;`.

Comment: This fixed my problems thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sentence is written properly, a simple way would be to count the number of spaces and add 1 to it:

```
int i = 0, words = 1;

//loop through the string (stop at the null terminating character)
while (sentence[i] != '\0') {
   if(sentence[i] == ' ') {words++;}
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while (getchar() !='\n');
```

to

```
while (getchar() !='\n')
```

Note the removal of the semicolon. With the semicolon, the loop does not perform the instructions you have given in the brackets of the loop.

If you want to solve all these problems easily next time, use the flags of your compiler and enable complete warnings.

If you're using `gcc`, use the flags `-Wall` and `-Wextra`. `-Wall` will give you extra warnings, including one for your silly mistake. `-Wextra` will make all the warnings you get into errors, making sure that you pay attention to them.

Answer (score -1):

ch = getchar(); needs to be inside the while loop. Otherwise, ch never updates. Also, don't forget the brackets for the if statement. And change getchar() != '\n' in the while loop to ch!='\n'

Comment: Hey man, i tried that but all it does is print an extra line after the original print and the answer is still wrong. Thanks though.

Comment: Read my new answer. I found 2 more errors in your code

Comment: After i tried that, once you enter in the sentence pressing enter only creates a new line infinietly.

Comment: Do you see anything else that is off? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you post the updated code I suggested and a sample input? Also, remove the semi-colon after the while condition